# Transferring contents from dictionary into a table

Tags: python

I have a dictionary containing:

```
dct = {'SA':3, 'MC':4, 'UG':6}
```

and I want to put the contents from the dictionary into a table as such:

```
table = [['SA':3],['MC':4],['UG':6]]
```

I would like to know what method suits best, as simply appending the dictionary into a table would somehow still have the '{}' in it. Regards.

Comment: What exactly is `['SA':3]`? a `dict` or `list`?

Comment: `map(list, dct.items())`?

Comment: Man what are `tables` exactly?

Comment: Don't confuse how something is printed on the console; this is simply a human-friendly way of showing the object that is referenced by the name. If you need to print the contents of the dictionary in a specific way, then describe your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the dict's items to a 'table like' list, use

diclist = list(dict.items())

this code uses prettytable module to actually table each key and value pair of a dict.

hope this helps.

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

def dicttable(dic):
    diclis = list(dic.items())  
    table = PrettyTable(['KEY','VALUE'])

    for k, v in diclis:
        table.add_row([k, v])

    print(table)

dicttable({'SA':3, 'MC':4, 'UG':6})
```